# Drools : drlDumper.dump() gives null pointer error

Tags: java, drools

I am new to drools, i am trying to create .drl from .xml rules file by using drools API. Below is the code used for conversion

```
    Reader source = new InputStreamReader(
            DroolsTest.class.getResourceAsStream(xmlFileName));
    XmlPackageReader xmlPackageReader = new XmlPackageReader(new SemanticModules());                
    PackageDescr pkgDesc = xmlPackageReader.read(source);
    DrlDumper drlDumper = new DrlDumper();
    String drl = drlDumper.dump(pkgDesc);
    System.out.println(drl);
    return drl;
```

Here is the exception stack trace

> [Error: null pointer: pkg.namespace] [Near : {... @code{ ....}]
>                ^ [Line: 1, Column: 1]   at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:427)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeAccessor(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:140)
>     at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.optimize(ASTNode.java:159)     at
>   org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:115)    at
>   org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86)    at
>   org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:113)
>     at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:930)  at
>   org.mvel2.templates.res.CompiledExpressionNode.eval(CompiledExpressionNode.java:45)
>     at org.mvel2.templates.res.TextNode.eval(TextNode.java:42)  at
>   org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime.execute(TemplateRuntime.java:285)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime.execute(TemplateRuntime.java:247)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime.execute(TemplateRuntime.java:255)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime.execute(TemplateRuntime.java:207)
>     at org.drools.compiler.lang.DrlDumper.dump(DrlDumper.java:59)   at
>   com.sample.DroolsTest.convertXmlToDrlFile(DroolsTest.java:65)     at
>   com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:34) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:360)
>     ... 17 more

Can someone please help me get rid of this issue.